# Using a hash as a factory in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, factory

I want to use a hash to instantiate objects of a certain type, however issues soon arise because the hash will only instantiate one instance, and then forever 'point' to that instance.

```
class Person
end

factory = { "make_person" => Person.new }

a = factory["make_person"]
b = factory["make_person"]

a == b
=> true
```

Even if the hash points to a method, say for instance `make_person`, which calls inside of it `Person.new`, it will still forever point to a single instance.

Anybody have a workaround for this? Thanks much.

Answer (score 4):

The object (instance of `Person`) is being assigned to the "make_person" key.

Everytime you ask for the `"make_person"` key you get back that object.

You need to make the initialization of a `Person` lazy using a lambda.

```
factory = { "make_person" => lambda { Person.new } }

factory["make_person"].call
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is that a hash is the wrong thing to use for this.

Why not use a plain old Ruby class?

```
class Factory
  def self.[](type)
    case type
    when "make_person"
      Person.new
    when "make_other_thing"
      # ...
    end
  end
end

a = Factory["make_person"]
b = Factory["make_person"]
a == b # => false
```

If you want to get a little fancier:

```
class Factory
  class << self
    def [](type)
      return send(type) if respond_to?(type)
      raise "I don't know how to do `#{type}'!"
    end

    def make_person
      Person.new
    end

    def make_other_thing
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

...but then you could just call `Factory.make_person`, so the `[]` method seems superfluous.

If you really, *really* want to use a Hash for something there's no reason to use a Hash for, you could do this:

```
factory = {
  "make_person" => -> { Person.new }
}

a = factory["make_person"][]
b = factory["make_person"][]
a == b # => false
```

Or this:

```
factory = Hash.new do |_, key|
  case key
  when "make_person"
    Person.new
  when "make_other_thing"
    # ...
  end
}

a = factory["make_person"]
b = factory["make_person"]
a == b # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the same instance of `Person`, not some new instantiation of `Person`.

Let's dig:

```
[3] pry(main)> factory = {}
=> {}
[4] pry(main)> factory.object_id
=> 70344866826960
[5] pry(main)> class Person
[5] pry(main)* end
=> nil
[6] pry(main)> factory["make_person"] = Person.new
=> #<Person:0x007ff4e4136038>
```

Person is instantiated, let's check it's object_id:

```
[7] pry(main)> factory["make_person"].object_id
=> 70344887611420
```

Let's assign it to variable a:

```
[8] pry(main)> a = factory["make_person"]
=> #<Person:0x007ff4e4136038>
```

Let's assign it to variable b:

```
[9] pry(main)> b = factory["make_person"]
=> #<Person:0x007ff4e4136038>
```

Now both a & b are pointing to the same object as shown by the object_id

```
[10] pry(main)> a.object_id
=> 70344887611420
[11] pry(main)> b.object_id
=> 70344887611420
```

As Kris points out there are a few ways to get the behavior your after, but the above is important for you to grok.

An example on how to make sure a new person is instantiated every time you call `factory["make_person"]`:

```
factory["make_person"] = lambda { Person.new }.call
=> #<Person:0x007ff4e0fa6ba8>
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you want it to be a hash. But if you insist, here we go:

```
factory = Hash.new do |_, key|
  blueprints = { "make_person" => Person }
  blueprints[key].new
end

person_x = factory["make_person"]
person_y = factory["make_person"]

person_x.object_id == person_y.object_id # => false
```